# Regex search for C style cast and replace with static_cast for C++ in Notepad++

Tags: c++, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find C style casts `(int) (float)` etc and search & replace them with `std::static_cast` but am having difficulties with the Regex capture groups.

Example Code:
`Point pt((int)(it.size*cn), 1);`

Should be replace to:
`Point pt(std::static_cast<int>((it.size*cn)), 1);`

The following regex matches the pattern:
`(\(int\))\([^ ]*\)`

When I try to replace the match with the second capture group (whatever is casted), it replaces everything.

The result I get is:
`Point pt(std::static_cast<int>((int)(it.size*cn)), 1);`
Using replace with:
`std::static_cast<int>\($0\)`

The regex does not have to infer the type, I am just searching for `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Zero index is whole regex match. Your two capture groups has indexes 1 and 2. Try something like `std::static_cast<$1>\($2\)`.

Also `static_cast` is a keyword and does not require `std::` namespace specifier. And usually in regex substitution pattern there is no need to escape braces.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

**Find What**: `\(int\)\(([^()]*)\)`
**Replace With**: `std::static_cast<int>\(\($1\)\)`

**Quick description**

- `\(int\)\(` - matches literal `(int)(`
- `([^()]*)` - captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - matches `)`.

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C(int%5C)%5C((%5B%5E()%5D*)%5C)):

[image]

See the Notepad++ screenshot with settings and demo:

[image]

Comment: If there can be nested parentheses, replace `\(int\)(\(([^()]++|(?1))*\))` with `std::static_cast<int>\($1\)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead: `\((int)\)\s*(\([^\)]*\))`

With a replacement string: `std::static_cast<$1>$2`

[LIVE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/thD5bR/1)

Note that using regex for this task is generally impractical, as a regex can't be used to parse C syntax properly.